# __react-router/v4__How to access history instance in BrowserRouter?

Tags: redux, react-router

I want to write a redux-middleware to handle history pushState in a react-router v4 application.

The problem is that I cannot access correct instance of `history` in BrowserRouter easily as it was created within BrowserRouter via `createHistory`.

My question: Is there an easy way to pass `history` singleton to BrowserRouter component?

Anyway, this example doesn't work anymore.

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/7f6706dab4827afc1c26a58418f8ef8c8ab40125/website/examples/Redux.js

Comment: Look at this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45183218/browserrouter-in-react-with-typescript/56693944#56693944

Answer (score 1):

In the current alpha version there is no *good* way to do this. There are workarounds involving either creating your own `<___Router>` component or accessing the `history` methods through the `context.router` variable (and passing that to your action so that it can be used by your middleware).

In the upcoming beta, you will have the option of creating a `history` instance and passing it to a `<Router>`, which will allow you to do navigation outside of the components.

```js
// history.js
import { createHistory } from 'history'
export default createHistory()

// index.js
import history from './history'
render((
  <Router history={history}>
    <App />
  </Router>
), holder)

// middleware.js
import history from './history'
export default store => dispatch => action => {
  if (action.type === 'ROUTING_ACTION') {
    history.push('/new_location')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I temporarily solved this issue which I assume happens with react-router v4.( I also have react-router-dom), like so:

Passing the history object from the component(selector) as argument to the action creator and then in the action creator definition calling history.push('/new-route')

```
export function register(user, history) { 
// this history is the argument from the register call in the component
    return function (dispatch) {
         dispatch(initRequest()); // show spinner or something
         return Auth.register(user)
             .then(()=> {
                dispatch(registerSuccess());
                history.push('/new-route');

        }).catch((err)=> dispatch(setErrorMessage()))
    }
}
```

also I have to point out that createHistory did not work for me, I had to do:

```
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'
const history = createBrowserHistory();
```