# <BrowserRouter> ignores the history prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I was using the following code from an online course for React routing:

```
import { Router, Route, browserHistory } from 'react-router';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
     <Route path="/" component={App></Route>
     <Route path="/One" component={One}></Route>

     <Route path="/Two" component={Two}></Route>
  </Router>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

It gave me a following error `'react-router' does not contain an export named 'browserHistory'.`

I did some research and found that I was using React Router v4, and the above code was for v3, so i found that I should be using `<BrowserRouter>` instead of `<Router>` so I changed my code to:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
   <BrowserRouter history={History}>

     <div> 
    <Route path="/" component={App}></Route>

    <Route path="/One" component={One}></Route>

    <Route path="/Two" component={Two}></Route>


    <Route path="*" component={NoMatch}></Route>

  </div></BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

History I have in a separate file:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'

export default createBrowserHistory();
```

Now the page loads without an error but if I use Developer tools, I can see a warning:

```
Warning: <BrowserRouter> ignores the history prop. To use a custom history, use `import { Router }` instead of `import { BrowserRouter as Router }`."
```

Another issue is that `<Route path="*" component="NoMatch}></Route>` only supposed to load `NoMatch` component when no path specified in the router but it loads on every page, regardless.
Can anyone help figure out how can I fix the issues?

Comment: Look at this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45183218/browserrouter-in-react-with-typescript/56693944#56693944

Answer (score 11):

I am assuming you are using react-router v4

**Firstly,** Instead of `<BrowserRouter>` make use of `<Router>`

```
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom';
```

You can get access to the history object's properties by using `<withRouter>` as mentioned [Here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md)

Export the component using `<withRouter>` , something like :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class SomeComponent extends Component {
render() {}
}
export default withRouter(SomeComponent);
```

**Secondly** , you can make use of `<Switch>` as it renders the first child `<Route>` or `<Redirect>` that matches the location

And you can wrap a `<Switch>` in a `<div>`  like this:

```
   <Router>
      <div> 
        <Switch>
         <Route path="/" component={App}></Route>
         <Route path="/One" component={One}></Route>
         <Route path="/Two" component={Two}></Route>
         <Route component={NoMatch}></Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
   </Router>
```

NOTE : Last Route doesn't have `path="*"`

You can read more about `<Switch>` on a [ReactTraining Github](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Switch.md)

If you want to read more about React Router V4 or `<withRouter>` , You can read on this [Medium Article](https://medium.com/@AkyunaAkish/understanding-react-router-4-df73a66d96c4)

Comment: This code gives me an error `You should not use <Switch> outside a <Router>` even though Switch is inside the Router...

Comment: I have updated the answer , Hope it will make things clearer

Comment: He should not use `<Router>` rather `<BrowserRouter>` and just remove reference to history in `<BrowserRouter history={History}>` because it is implied in V4. Router and BrowserRouter are not interchangeable components

Answer (score 2):

You can only use `history` with `<Router>` hence the error message. 
See the API on the sidebar in react-router docs.

**Browser Router**

```
<BrowserRouter>
 basename: string
 getUserConfirmation: func
 forceRefresh: bool
 keyLength: number
 children: node
```

**Router**

```
<Router>
 history: object
 children: node
```

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Router/history-object

As for the no match, you need a switch and to put the last component without a path. Right now you are grabbing every route with `path="*"`

Again, see docs https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/no-match

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/" exact component={Home}/>
  <Redirect from="/old-match" to="/will-match"/>
  <Route path="/will-match" component={WillMatch}/>
  <Route component={NoMatch}/>
</Switch>
```