# Path to endpoint isn't permanent (nginx/react)

Tags: reactjs, nginx, redirect, routes

I have an issue routing 2 react apps through nginx: I have a client app and an admin app, who both have `"homepage": "https://example.com/"` and `https://example.com/admin/` in their package.json (if that matters at all?).
I want to be able to access them from these endpoints, I can access /admin without any problem, but it automatically redirects me to the admin dashboard on /dashboard (and not /admin/dashboard). And as soon as i press reload, it sends me back a 404 from the client.

This is the relevant part of my nginx conf:

```
resolver 1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html/client/build/;
    index index.html;

location /admin {
        gzip_static on;
        alias /usr/share/nginx/html/admin/build/;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri /index.html =404;
    }

    location / {
        gzip_static on;
        alias /usr/share/nginx/html/client/build/;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri /index.html =404;
    }
```

I'm not even sure this has to do with nginx, could it be because of this piece of code in the admin's index.js?

```js
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
        AuthService.isLoggedIn() === true
            ? <Component {...props} />
            : <Redirect to={{
                pathname: '/',
                state: { from: props.location }
            }} />
    )} />
);

ReactDOM.render(
    <SnackbarProvider>
        <UserProvider>
            <Router history={hist} basename="/admin">
                <Switch>
                        [..]
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        </UserProvider>
    </SnackbarProvider>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

and routes in indexRoutes look like this:

```json
{ 
        path: "/",
        component: Login, 
        exact: true
},
{
    path: "/dashboard",
    sidebarName: "Accueil",
    navbarName: "Accueil",
    icon: Dashboard,
    component: DashboardPage,
    permissions: Permissions.Dashboard.value
}
...
```

I suspect this could be it since https://example.com/project/ 200 if you are coming from the admin dashboard, but 404 (on the "/" or client endpoint) if you just paste the url.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind i figured it out, it was indeed not nginx's fault,
the react Router was the default Router from `'react-router-dom'`, I changed it to be BrowserRouter.
So

```js
import {
    Router,
    Route,
    Switch
} from 'react-router-dom'
```

to

```js
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Route,
    Switch
} from 'react-router-dom'
```

Comment: I probably have to look at since I still catch the browser console warning I tried to avoid by using Router instead of BrowserRouter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48349138/browserrouter-ignores-the-history-prop